# What is the cooldown on companion gifts?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In Star Wars: The Old Republic, you can buy or acquire gifts for your companion characters. You can't give your companion a gift immediately after giving them one, but there's no cooldown indicators like there are for, say, medpacs.

How long do I need to wait between giving my companions gifts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if it's changed since January, but it was 30 seconds when I was playing. I'm pretty sure it puts a debuff on you which you can hover over to see the countdown.

Comment: It puts the debuff on your player, not the companion.

Comment: Also, getting another companion out won't change it in anyway, before anyone asks.

Answer (score 3):

[This changed in Patch 1.2](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/1.2.0/legacy).  There is no longer any cooldown, and the activation time is 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually see the timer on it as a debuff to your character.  The icon is above your health bar with the others.